# Chromium B.S.U. (game)

Tags: 18.04, games

The Chromium B.S.U. arcade game worked when I had 16.10, 17.04, and 17.10 (real fun but hard as heck to 'win'...), but after upgrading to 18.04LTS it appears to load when you click it, but never does and sometimes will instead display that it had a problem closing and wants to report the bug (so I let it). The website for the game has no way to contact it's owner/creator, so I just hope it somehow just begins to work again...
Anyone got any ideas other than uninstall and find another similar arcade game? (and can you recommend one?)

Comment: Start from command line and add the error it shows into the question. It might have an issue with gdm or the new device drivers. "The website for the game has no way to contact it's owner/creator"  https://wiki.debian.org/Games/Team is where you can find them

Comment: the link above shows nothing on owner/creator of Chromium BSU...
Starting from command line? There's this icon I click on for the game... and the error that occasionally pops up just says the game had a problem closing - noting about it opening/playing... not sure what Rinzwind is directing me to do...

Comment: 1. Yes it does. That game is maintained by a group of users and you can find them there. The maintainer is the group.  2. starting something from commandline is basic linux usage. Find the command it starts. Use it to start from commandline, wait for the error to show on command line. It probably is `chromium-bsu` looking at a man page: https://www.mankier.com/6/chromium-bsu

Comment: $ sudo chromium-bsu
[sudo] password for cf73: 
sudo: chromium-bsu: command not found

Comment: did man for chromium-bsu and tried the debug:
$ chromium-bsu --debug
Generating random sequences
dbus[13097]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1362.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rd
Then up pops the error: The application Chromium-B.S.U. has closed unexpectedly... and it sends an error report...

Comment: I have no problem playing the game on my setup (16.04>--18.04--), I think this is a hardware-specific or configuration issue or something....

Comment: I had no problem playing the game either - until upgrade to 18.04... could it be because my laptop is 32-bit w/2Gb CPU + 1Gb RAM (shared w/GPU) ~ also, I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04, not 16.04 to 18.04... - perhaps Sederholm's computer is more 'robust'...  of course they said my video crashing issue while on 17.10 was from 'dirty' computer and 'undersized fan', but once upgraded to 18.04 the 'issue' went away ~ so much for hardware/config on that one ;-)

Comment: Still not working -any recommendations for a similar type ubuntu game?

Comment: OK... will instead look for an alternate that will run using the **WIN**dows**E**mulator...